# How to not use DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

When using the new template for ASP.NET Core 6.0, which includes `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` the DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware is automatically added. I would like to not use this middleware so that I can provide a consistent error response in all environments.

Is there anyway to put my custom error handling before this middleware, or prevent it from being included? Or to remove it after it's been included?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently you can't disable `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` in minimal hosting model for development environment since it [is set up](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebApplicationBuilder.cs#L245) without any options to configure. So options are:

1. Use/switch back to [generic host model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0) (the one with `Startup`s) and skip the `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` call.
2. Do not use development environment
3. Setup custom exception handling. `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` relies on the fact that exception was not handled later down the pipeline so adding custom exception handler right after the building the app should do the trick:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, func) =>
{
    try
    {
        await func();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();

        // Preserve the status code that would have been written by the server automatically when a BadHttpRequestException is thrown.
        if (e is BadHttpRequestException badHttpRequestException)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = badHttpRequestException.StatusCode;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        }
        // log, write custom response and so on...
    }
});
```

Using [custom exception handler page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-handler-page) with `UseExceptionHandler` also should  (unless the handler itself throws ) work.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of the suggestions in #2 work. Custom exception handling with `UseExceptionHandler` never triggers, and the exception doesn't bubble up to any other middleware as it's caught in `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` and not passed further.

Comment: @ColinDeClue I have tested this code locally and it worked for me (both for `UseExceptionHandler` (note that you need to create an endpoint/page/action for it)). Can you please share the repro somewhere on the github? Also note that `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` is executed after [all custom registered middlewares](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.cs#L94).

Comment: Well, turns out it DOES work just fine... I had a `try...catch` in the controller I was using for testing...

Comment: @PoulBak not following you. the provided code was tested and it works. Also as far as I remember `UseExceptionHandler` also worked when I tested it.

Comment: `UseExceptionHandler` does work (sorry for the confusion, it was indeed caused by my failing ExceptionHandler page).

Comment: @PoulBak No problem. If I remember correctly I had exactly the same issue with `UseExceptionHandler` when tried it for the first time)

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to skip `DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware` is not using the `Development` [environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686).

You can modify the `Properties/launchSettings.json` file, change `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to **anything** but `Development`.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:43562",
      "sslPort": 44332
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "api1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7109;http://localhost:5111",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "MyDevelopment"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "MyDevelopment"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your app, change all `builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()` to `builder.Environment.IsEnvironment("MyDevelopment")`.